# creating notifications with AwesomeNotifitcations without using Atleast one NotificationButton in NotificationLayout.MediaPlayer style causes error

Tags: android, flutter, notifications

creating notifications with AwesomeNotifitcations without using Atleast one NotificationButton in NotificationLayout.MediaPlayer style causes following error:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
[        ] W/System.err(21896):     at me.carda.awesome_notifications.notifications.NotificationBuilder.setMediaPlayerLayout(NotificationBuilder.java:1064)
[        ] W/System.err(21896):     at me.carda.awesome_notifications.notifications.NotificationBuilder.setLayout(NotificationBuilder.java:836)
[        ] W/System.err(21896):     at me.carda.awesome_notifications.notifications.NotificationBuilder.getNotificationBuilderFromModel(NotificationBuilder.java:393)
[        ] V/MediaPlayer(21896): resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
[        ] V/MediaPlayer(21896): cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
[        ] W/System.err(21896):     at me.carda.awesome_notifications.notifications.NotificationBuilder.createNotification(NotificationBuilder.java:110)
[        ] W/System.err(21896):     at me.carda.awesome_notifications.notifications.NotificationSender.showNotification(NotificationSender.java:209)
[        ] W/System.err(21896):     at me.carda.awesome_notifications.notifications.NotificationSender.doInBackground(NotificationSender.java:128)
[        ] W/System.err(21896):     at me.carda.awesome_notifications.notifications.NotificationSender.doInBackground(NotificationSender.java:34)
[        ] W/System.err(21896):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
[        ] W/System.err(21896):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[        ] W/System.err(21896):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
[        ] W/System.err(21896):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
[        ] W/System.err(21896):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
[        ] W/System.err(21896):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1013)
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to provide atleast one NotificationButton(actionButtons property) in createNotification method of awesomeNotification plugin